# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, persistence.xml

This is a fairly straightforward question but I couldn't find a proper answer for it.

I have set a few environment variables in my Elastic Beanstalk environment. The application deployed is a Java Webapp built using JPA (EclipseLink).

I want to access these variables from my persistence.xml file so I can run the application in different environments by just passing environment variables instead of modifying persistence.xml every time.

Is there some way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, check this two answers, I think that should work for you
1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8839779/1535071
2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37891033/1535071