# Environment specific ebextensions Beanstalk commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have a spring-boot application for which I need to specify graphite server and port (to send metrics). For that to work, I have to install and configure `statsd`. I do that using the `ebextensions` file.

```
commands:
  01_nodejs_install:
    command: sudo yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
    ignoreErrors: true

  02_mkdir_statsd:
    command: mkdir /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

  03_fetch_statsd:
    command: git clone https://github.com/etsy/statsd.git /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

  04_change_example_config:
    command: "cat exampleConfig.js | sed 's/2003/<graphite-port>/g' | sed 's/graphite.example.com/<my-graphite-server>/g' > config.js"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd

  05_run_statsd:
    command: setsid node stats.js config.js >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
```

The problem with this configuration is that I can specify only 1 graphite server here for all environments.

So I decided to move commands 04 and 05 into `container_commands`. I am thinking of defining an environment variable called `ENV_NAME` *using the beanstalk console/UI*, and set it to `dev`, `qa`, or `prod` according to the environment. Then I can use `test` option of `container_commands` to run 04 and 05 commands only for specific environment based on this `ENV_NAME`.

So my problem is - how can I use AWS console to define environment variable? I tried using Beanstalk console to define my variable as explained in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/envvar.html)  but it did not work. I also [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-custom-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-aws-ebs) (see the answer with 5 upvotes) that this method sets only JVM properties and not ENV variables.

I cannot define environment variable using `ebextensions` because then I'll have the same problem - can't define different env vars for different envs :)

So I need help with either:

- Set the `ENV_NAME` environment variable using beanstalk UI.

Or

- Suggest a way to use `ENV_NAME` system property in `container_commands` to condition whether or not to run the command based on the value of `ENV_NAME`.

And in case you know a simpler/better way to specify different Graphite servers for different environments, please feel free to pitch in.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The way I resolved this was to define `ENV_NAME` as `dev` and `prod` in dev and prod environments respectively and use the following `ebextensions` configuration.

```
commands:
  01_nodejs_install:
    command: sudo yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
    ignoreErrors: true

  02_mkdir_statsd:
    command: mkdir /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

  03_fetch_statsd:
    command: git clone https://github.com/etsy/statsd.git /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

container_commands:
  04a_container_change_example_config:
    command: "cat exampleConfig.js | sed 's/2003/<graphite-dev-port>/g' | sed 's/graphite.example.com/<graphite-dev-host>/g' > config.js"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
    test: '[ "${ENV_NAME}" == "dev" ]'

  04b_container_change_example_config:
    command: "cat exampleConfig.js | sed 's/2003/<graphite-prod-port>/g' | sed 's/graphite.example.com/<graphite-prod-host>/g' > config.js"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
    test: '[ "${ENV_NAME}" == "prod" ]'

  05_run_statsd:
    command: setsid node stats.js config.js >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
```

Using `test` I can condition the execution of the `container command` on the `ENV_NAME` property which I have already defined in the beanstalk environment.

Comment: This looks good. Just wondering how you found out what syntax to use for the test. Do you know of an official aws doc for that? Thanks.

Comment: @Dennis I don't remember exactly how I figured out but an example on some AWS documentation page helped. Perhaps [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html). There must have been some trial and error on my part to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess it is actually just bash scripting?

Comment: Being unfamiliar with bash scripting,  [this reference](https://devhints.io/bash) helped me make sense of some peculiarities of the syntax.

Comment: Both tests are returning positive for me.

Comment: [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) mentions the use of `test` to execute a command or not

Comment: @Nik Where did you define `ENV_NAME`?

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the answer by @Nik:

Instead of manually adding an environment variable `ENV_NAME`, you could also obtain the actual environment name and store that in `ENV_NAME` automatically. This is achieved using `option_settings` in your `ebextensions` config file.

For example:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    ENV_NAME: '`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`'  # assign the actual env name to ENV_NAME

container_commands:
  0100_execute_only_in_dev:
    command: echo "this is the development environment"  # this will turn up in ebactivity.log
    test: '[[ $ENV_NAME = "dev" ]]'
```

A side note, for those who are not so familiar with shell scripting, like me: **the spaces in the test expression are important** ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586839)).

### Update: Amazon Linux 2

As of 2021, [Amazon Linux 2 is the new standard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html). Amazon Linux 2 uses [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.hooks) instead of the `container_commands` in `.ebextensions`.

Here's a bash script equivalent to the `0100_execute_only_in_dev` container command defined above, that can be used as a platform hook on Amazon Linux 2:

`0100_execute_only_in_dev.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $ENV_NAME = "dev" ]
# the following output will end up in "/var/log/eb-hooks.log"
then echo "this is the development environment" 
fi
```

The shell script requires execution permission, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.hooks.more), and can be placed in any of the subdirectories of `.platform/hooks` and/or `.platform/confighooks`, in your source bundle, depending on the applicable deployment phase (`prebuild`, `predeploy`, or `postdeploy`). See the deployment [workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.workflow) for more information. It also helps to inspect `/var/log/eb-engine.log`, to see what exactly happens during the deployment.

Note that platform hooks also have access to the EB environment properties.

Comment: This is a list of other properties that can be used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkenvironment

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in this Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html), but I'll put it a little in my words: 
Since you are running a spring-boot application, you can create different 'application.properties' files, like this:

[image]

Inside each file you can place your graphite (or whatever) configuration:

In my application-dev.yml:

[image]

And in my application-prod.yml:

[image]

As you can see there is a configuration for each environment.

You can run your application with different maven profiles, in this case, let's say: dev and prod... In my case my 'dev' profile is set by default, so when the application starts it will load the dev profile and therefore, the application-dev.yml configuration.

A snippet of my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            ...
```

Then, when you run your application with each profile, it will load the desired .yml file

Let's see, if I run:

```
java -jar mywar.war
```

My console loads the dev profile (because remember it is my default profile)

[image]

But if I specify the prod profile, like:

```
java -jar mywar.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

My console will show:

[image]

To set the environment variable in Elastic Beanstalk, go to Configuration -> Software configuration:

[image]

And set `spring.profile.active`, like this:

[image]

One last comment: **Do not confuse Environment Properties with Environment Tags!**

- Environment Properties: The ones I just showed you: The environment variables.
- Environment Tags: Elastic Beanstalk tags for resources, as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this won't help in my case. Note that my goal here is to configure `statsd` and not to configure the spring-boot application. I am already using the method you described to specify different `Graphite` settings for different environments *in my application*. However, I want to configure `statsd` which runs as a daemon on each host alongside the spring-boot application.